# Sonata Symfony - Custom field in ListFields

Tags: php, symfony-sonata

I would like to filter inside a field.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
    $listMapper
            ->add('users')
            ->add('books')
            ->add('readed')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
    ;
}
```

So, I have this table. Books is an ArrayCollection with all the books than this users has read. (For each book, they have a parameter enabled) I would like to display only the enabled books readed by the user. for now they show me all books readed by the users.

i was planning to create inside my entity users a function returning all enabled books but i didnt think its the better way.

Thank you for your suggestions,

Comment: Alternative solution: Using twig for filtering. I dont know if it can help someome